# Google Maps Javascript api zoom issue with svg marker

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, firefox, svg, zooming

I've a simple map with an svg file as marker icon.
When the map is loaded no problem but, if i try to zoom in or out, image became bigger and is cutoff.
This behavior change from browser to browser:

- Google Chrome starts ok but if you try to zoom it reveals the issue.
- Safari works well
- Firefox shows nothing

I think is an svg related issue, but i can't find where the bug is.
I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5sg32psg/) with this code

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.373743,4.893114)
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var icon = {
    url: "http://filippopoderini.com/marker-07.svg",
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(23,60),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(46,60)
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.373743, 4.893114),
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: icon,
});
```

and this is svg code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="-2339.1 129.2 289 375" style="enable-background:new -2339.1 129.2 289 375;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#32ABDF;stroke:#424242;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#A9A9A9;stroke:#424242;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:#424242;}
    .st3{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st4{fill:#32ABDF;}
</style>
<g>
    <path class="st2" d="M-2298,370.3L-2298,370.3c-5-5.3-9.5-10.9-13.5-16.8c-16.1-23.5-24.6-51.1-24.6-79.7
        c0-78,63.5-141.5,141.5-141.5s141.5,63.5,141.5,141.5c0,28.6-8.5,56.2-24.6,79.7c-4,5.9-8.6,11.6-13.5,16.8l-0.1,0.1l-103.4,129.1
        L-2298,370.3z"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M-2194.6,135.2c37,0,71.8,14.4,97.9,40.6c26.2,26.2,40.6,60.9,40.6,97.9c0,28-8.3,55-24,78
        c-3.9,5.8-8.4,11.3-13.2,16.5l-0.2,0.2l-0.1,0.2l-101,126.1l-101-126.1l-0.1-0.2l-0.2-0.2c-4.8-5.1-9.2-10.6-13.1-16.4
        c-15.8-23-24.1-50-24.1-78c0-37,14.4-71.8,40.6-97.9C-2266.3,149.6-2231.6,135.2-2194.6,135.2 M-2194.6,129.2
        c-79.8,0-144.5,64.7-144.5,144.5c0,30.2,9.3,58.2,25.1,81.4h0l0,0c4.1,6,8.7,11.8,13.7,17.1l105.7,132l105.7-131.9
        c5-5.4,9.6-11.1,13.7-17.2l0,0c15.8-23.2,25.1-51.2,25.1-81.4C-2050.1,193.9-2114.8,129.2-2194.6,129.2L-2194.6,129.2z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <path class="st3" d="M-2194.6,198.3c-0.6,0-1.3,0.3-1.7,0.7l-56.7,59c-0.9,0.9-0.9,2.4,0.1,3.3c0.9,0.9,2.5,0.9,3.4-0.1l7.5-7.8
        v63.2h30.8v-54.5h33.2v54.5h30.8v-63.2l7.5,7.8c0.5,0.5,1.1,0.7,1.7,0.7c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.7-0.7c0.9-0.9,1-2.4,0.1-3.3l-56.7-59
        C-2193.3,198.5-2193.9,198.3-2194.6,198.3z M-2170.8,210v7.2l14.2,14.8v-22H-2170.8z M-2206.4,266.9v49.8h23.7v-49.8H-2206.4z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your svg icon is **really** big (728x945), maybe if you scale it down to start  it might behave more reasonably (that said, it does seem to work at first, seems like this might be a bug in the svg processing in the API).

Comment: Just tried to scale down svg without any improvment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to *explicitly* update marker icon once map zoom changed as demonstrated below:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  marker.setIcon(icon);
});
```

Modified [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/xpuzp0dk/)

```js
function initMap() {

  var map;
  var polyLine;
  var polyOptions;



  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.373743, 4.893114)
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var icon = {
    url: "http://filippopoderini.com/marker-07.svg",
    //anchor: new google.maps.Point(23, 60),
    //scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(46, 60),
    size: new google.maps.Size(46, 60)
  }

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.373743, 4.893114),
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: icon,
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      marker.setIcon(icon);
  });  

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
#map-canvas { 
    height: 400px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

> P.S. Have been verified in Chrome `v51`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it after some debugging. I missed the width/height of the SVG itself. This needs to be the same width/height as the viewBox. Then the SVG got resized correctly when zoomed in / out.